# Flutter setEnabledSystemUIMode leaves a gap on top of screen (Android only)

Tags: flutter

I'm using this code to hide the status bar on my Flutter app.

It works fine, except on **Android devices**: It leaves a huge gap at the top of the screen (it may be hard to see, but I'm talking about the black gap above the dark shaded scaffold).

```html
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.immersive,
    overlays: [],
  );
```

Here's the widget:

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Scroll Cancellation Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _test,
          child: const Text('Press'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Android:**
[image]

**IOS:**

[image]

The only way to cover the whole screen would be by using `edgeToEdge`, but that'd defeat the purpose entirely...

How can I hide the status/bottom bar from android devices?

Comment: Show the related widget tree.

Comment: Done. Check it out.

Comment: Try to wrap with `SafeArea(top:false`

Comment: Do you use `SafeArea` anywhere? Have you tried using `MediaQuery.removePadding(top: true, bottom: true, left: true, right: true, child: ...`)?

Comment: @Md. Yeasin Sheikh Same result.